# Calculating cumulative sum over dates but excluding data that is removed on later dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, select, sum

Let me see if I can explain it well.

I have data that looks like this for like fixed deposits

```
Placement Date | Maturity Date | Amount
2020-01-30     | 2020-03-30    | 50000
2020-02-05     | 2020-05-28    | 20000
2020-03-31     | 2020-05-30    | 7000
2020-04-13     | 2020-07-30    | 60000
```

My desired output would be on a monthly basis get the cumulative amount but to exclude those that have already matured.

```
Month      | Amount
2020-01-31 | 50000
2020-02-29 | 70000
2020-03-31 | 27000 (due to the 50000 maturing on 03-30)
2020-04-30 | 87000
2020-05-31 | 60000 (due to the 20000 and 7000 maturing on 05-28 and 05-30)
```

So far I have used the over clause to get the cumulative sum but I haven't a clue how to remove those that have matured in the following months.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a calendar table (you can easily find examples on how to build one online, it can be reused for other reporting purposes).

Then you can do something like this.

```
SELECT d.theDate, SUM(dp.Amount)
FROM dbo.AllDates d
JOIN dbo.Deposits dp
    ON d.theDate BETWEEN dp.placementDate AND dp.MaturityDate
WHERE d.LastDayOfTheMonth = 1
GROUP BY d.theDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a recursive cte to generate the dates, then a join on the original table, and aggregation:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        datefromparts(year(min(placement_date)), month(min(placement_date)), 1) dt,
        max(maturity_date) max_dt
    from mytable
    union all
    select 
        dateadd(month, 1, dt),
        max_dt
    from cte 
    where dateadd(month, 1, dt) < max_dt
)
select eomonth(c.dt) month, coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) amount
from cte c
left join mytable t
    on eomonth(c.dt) between t.placement_date and t.maturity_date
group by c.dt
order by c.dt
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2dfc7e84f670a64f433c28493bec3833)**:

```
month      | amount
:--------- | -----:
2020-01-31 |  50000
2020-02-29 |  70000
2020-03-31 |  27000
2020-04-30 |  87000
2020-05-31 |  60000
2020-06-30 |  60000
2020-07-31 |      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE directly on each row.  That is, expand each row to determine what the value is at the end of the month.  And then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select eomonth(placement_date) as eom, maturity_date, amount
      from t
      where eomonth(placement_date) < maturity_date
      union all
      select eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, eom)), maturity_date,
             (case when eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, eom)) < maturity_date then amount else 0 end)
      from cte 
      where eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, eom)) <= eomonth(maturity_date)
     )
select eom, sum(amount)
from cte
group by eom
order by eom;
```

There are two subtleties in this query:

- One month later than the end-of-the-month may not be the last day of the last month.  So, 2020-02-29 + 1 month is 2020-03-29, rather than 2020-03-31.  Hence the use of `eomonth()` in the recursive part.
- You want the final month for the maturity date to be in the result set.  Hence the `<=` in the recursive part.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efd79b9ff092c4575ef62afaf7f56323) is a db<>fiddle.